# Kustomize configMapGenerator

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, kustomize

In kubernetes kustomize.yml, when I use configMapGenerator to pass in some values as env, can I access those variables in deployed springboot application, application.properties file?

kustomize.yml

```
...
configMapGenerator:
  - name: test-app-config
    env: ./test/applicationsetup.env
...
```

test/applicationsetup.env

```
some_key=data1
some_key1=data2
```

application.properties

```
APPLICATION_KEY=${some_key}
APPLICATION_KEY1=${some_key1}
```

Comment: It looks like you are looking for [this](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/tree/master/examples/springboot)

Comment: Actually i am looking to do other way around. Looking to pass some_key, some_key1 value to the application.properties. Not sure if it will be available.

Comment: It looks like you are looking at [this](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/1440)

Comment: Yes. Thanks Hanx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I missed to add configMapRef inside container where I was trying to access the data.

```
containers:
        - name: test-container
          image: <image>
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: test-app-config
```